# Slideshow of images in Swing

Tags: java, swing, slideshow

i have to view some images in Slideshow..
For that i have loaded few images and written this code.
inside the code i am creating a frame and adding a label in which i am Setting the Image icon of the label.
but when i run my program the frame gets hang.

this is My code bellow.,
can anyone Help please..!

```
 public class Slideshow extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {

        File outputFolder;
        ScreenVO screenVO;
        ImageHelper helper;

        public Slideshow(File outputFolder, ScreenVO screenVO) {
            this.outputFolder = outputFolder;
            this.screenVO = screenVO;
            this.helper = new ImageHelper();
        }

        public void start(final File outputFolder, ScreenVO screenVO) {
            try {

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

                frame.add(panel);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
                        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_ESCAPE) {
                            frame.dispose();
                        }

                    }
                });

                //screenVO.getScreen().setFullScreenWindow(frame);

                /* frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); */

                        File[] listOfFile = PhotoliciousUtils
                                .filterJPEGImagesFromFolder(outputFolder
                                        .listFiles());
                        List list = PhotoliciousUtils.nameOfFiles(listOfFile);
                        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                            File[] listOfFiles = PhotoliciousUtils
                                    .filterJPEGImagesFromFolder(outputFolder
                                            .listFiles());

                            if (list.size() > listOfFiles.length) {
                                list.clear();
                                list = PhotoliciousUtils.nameOfFiles(listOfFiles);
                            } else {
                                for (final File file : listOfFiles) {
                                    try {
                                        panel.removeAll();
                                        JLabel fullImage = new JLabel(helper
                                                .createThumbnails(file));
                                        panel.add(fullImage);
                                        Thread.sleep(5000);

                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static ScreenVO[] fetchListOfScreen() {
            ScreenVO[] listOfScreenVO = new ScreenVO[10];
            try {
                GraphicsDevice[] listOfScreen;
                GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment
                        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                listOfScreen = ge.getScreenDevices();
                for (int i = 0; i < listOfScreen.length; i++) {
                    ScreenVO screenVO = new ScreenVO();
                    if (i == 0) {
                        screenVO.setName("Primary Screen" + " : "
                                + listOfScreen[i].getDisplayMode().getWidth() + "x"
                                + listOfScreen[i].getDisplayMode().getHeight());
                    } else {
                        screenVO.setName("Screen" + i + 1 + " : "
                                + listOfScreen[i].getDisplayMode().getWidth() + "x"
                                + listOfScreen[i].getDisplayMode().getHeight());
                    }
                    screenVO.setScreen(listOfScreen[i]);
                    listOfScreenVO[i] = screenVO;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            return listOfScreenVO;
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    start(outputFolder, screenVO);
                }
            });
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `invokeLater()` in `doInBackground()`. That explicitly puts the code back to the Event Dispatch Thread - exactly what you're trying to avoid by using a SwingWorker. If the loading code is not particularly time consuming, you might get away simply by using a swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Otherwise, keep using a SwingWorker (or a custom thread) for the loading, and do only the access to swing components in EDT.

Also, while creating the components need to be done in the EDT, you should try to clearly separate that from the slideshow code. It does not belong to the background task. Create the window and the contents (wrapped with invokeLater), and then have a different method for changing the pictures (the timer approach is the simplest, so I'd start with that).

Comment: do you suggest to put the code within the invokeLater() to be put into the Constructor of Slideshow() ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I'd reorder the code roughly this way: a main class where I'd basically only do `invokeLater()` to call creation of the UI. Then after the UI is done start a timer for the slide show. (Or a swing worker, but that is needed only if the application feels more responsive that way).

Answer (score 1):

Create thread which will change the image after some time

```
Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
       try{
           Thead.sleep(1000);
           //write code here to set image to jLabel
       }catch(Exception e){
       }
   }
});
t.start()
```